# How to get costmap_2d to build on top of cartographer's /map?

Tags: ros, mapping, cartographer, ros-kinetic, costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd like to build a costmap on top of cartographer's map instead of say, gmaping, so I can run move_base on it for navigation. How do I go about doing this/

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/300102/how-to-get-costmap_2d-to-build-on-top-of-cartographer%27s-/map?/) by [asabet](https://answers.ros.org/users/35904/asabet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2018-08-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can just do this natively. As long as it provides the map on the correct topics (if you're using defaults, it'll work out of the box). All navigation looks for is the /map topic out of the box so if cartographer provides this, then you're done!

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2018-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1